# How to customize the row in the Table view in the iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need to customize my table view can anyone help me how to do this.

Actually I am having three sections in my tableview each one has one row and I want to make the third section row as an rounded rectangular of size 50 x 50.

Please guys help me how to do this...!!

Thanks in advance,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Manual](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18). Plus, there are a gazillion tutorials online, like [this one](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder).